# Meaning of "C’mon that segue tho."

Tags: sentence-meaning, idioms, informal-language

I am translating a Youtube video to Spanish; I am fairly comfortable with standard English but I have found an expression that I am not sure how to understand. Of course, I do not want the translation to Spanish, just to understand the meaning

The sentence is "C’mon that segue tho.", from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-g1O7UBNjQ) around the 1:00 mark. It starts talking about spirits tricking men, and goes into telling how using a documentary streaming service would help the viewers avoid those tricks (and then it explains it is his sponsor). Then the expression appears.

I understand this to be equivalent to "Come one that segue though.", but still it does not make much sense to me. My gut feeling is that it would be somewhat equivalent "Do you see how swiftly/cunningly I have switched to talking about my sponsor?" but I am not sure, and I do not know if I am missing some detail.

Also, is this something of an usual idiom or is it something that the video author has just made up and that can be understood only because of context?

Comment: Your interpretation is correct, and this is a common idiom. Here is some detail about the "that ... though" construction: https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/64323/evolution-noun-though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"C'mon" is "Come on" (not Come one).  It's a fairly common casual part of speech, which means something like "Listen, and understand me"  (I suppose it derives from "Come on towards my position").  A segue in a film is where the action moves from one scene to another without interruption.  Its can be used when there is an abrupt change in topic.  By saying "that segue", the speaker is asking you to think about it.  "Tho" or "though" could be used to link to the explanation of what was special about the segue.  In this case it seems to be unspoken, you have to figure that out from context

so it means "Listen to me, think about the way that the scene changed."

Answer (score 2):

That meaning of "C'mon" is shown at this link:

[Collins "come on" (3)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/come-on)
"You say 'Come on' to someone when you think that what they are saying is silly or unreasonable."
[In this case, it refers to what they are doing].

A "segue" is this usage
[Merriam-Webster "segue" (noun)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/segue)
"a transition made without pause or interruption"

The usage of "though" is similar to that of "come on", expressing surprise that the segue occurred.

That sentence might be said by a third party, watching the video (which is an advertisement), expressing surprise at the awkwardness of the transition that just occurred.

Since it is said by the narrator of the video and not by a third party, if falls into the category of insincere self-deprecation.